# Django - relação unique together

Tags: python, sql-server, django, aplicação-web

Oi, pessoal. Estou mexendo com um banco de dados de livros legado + Django. Nesse banco de dados tem uma tabela principal com informações de livros, onde cada livro recebe um indice e volume únicos juntos. Há outra tabela de empréstimo de livros e nisso mostra o índice e o volume de cada livro emprestado. Porém, na página que estou desenvolvendo ao invés de mostrar o indice e volume gostaria de mostrar o nome do livro. Para isso precisaria ir na tabela principal e resgatar o nome do livro que tem aquele indice e volume para mostrar. Porém não sei como posso fazer isso. Tô quebrando a cabeça para tentar achar a solução.

Alguém poderia me ajudar indicando o que posso ler para conseguir resolver?

Answer (score -2):

```
seu model:

class Livro(models.Model):
    indice = models.CharField(unique=True)
    volume = models.CharField(unique=True)
    nome = models.CharField()

sua view:
from <seu_arquivo_model> import Livro
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class LivroViewSet():

.
.
.

    def retorna_livro(indice, volume):
        livro = get_object_or_404(Livro, indice=indice, volume=volume)
        return livro.nome


Se houver o livro com esse indice e volume, ele retornará o nome daquele objeto Livro, se não, retorna 404(Not Found)
```